# How do I make my published web app that is installed on my IIS be accessed by another computer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web-deployment

I recently published an asp mvc app using IIS. The main page address is localhost/HR/Index.

How can I make another computer be able to access and use my web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get your computer ip address by cmd command 'ipconfig'.

   2. From another computer browser 'youtIPAddress:80/HR/Index'. Make sure the
      another computer is within your LAN.

Cheers.....

Comment: is there a way to change the ipaddress? I mean instead of "192.12.123.21:80/HR/Index", change it into "SomeWeb/HR/Index"?